# Google maps / Iframe dynamic src element

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iframe, src, google-maps-api-2

ok so my problem is I have an iframe that is meant to show googlemaps

The src of the iframe will be set to hit googlemaps with an address read from the database being inserted as a location

At the minute the frame is just pure white and no picture appears even, however if the src path is placed into a browser URL it works fine, the test url i have is
"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=27+Landseer+Street,+Belfast&size=500x300&sensor=false"

this is valid as you willl see if you put in an address bar.

My aim is to have three frames all named individually and then the src's set on them.
Here is my code so far

VB.NET
    Public Class About
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Session("recentAddressmap1") = ""
    Session("recentAddressmap2") = ""
    Session("recentAddressmap3") = ""
    Session("src1") = ""
    Session("src2") = ""
    Session("src3") = ""
    Dim recentCount As Integer
    recentCount = 0
    Dim addresstest As String = "27 Landseer Street"
    Dim words As String() = addresstest.Split(New Char() {" "c})

    ' Use For Each loop over words and display them
    Dim word As String
    Dim newaddress As String = ""
    Dim loopcounter As Integer = 0
    For Each word In words
        If loopcounter = 0 Then
            newaddress = word
            loopcounter = loopcounter + 1
        Else
            newaddress = newaddress & "+" & word
        End If
    Next
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' DO ENTRY RECENT 1 '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Session("recentAddressmap1") = newaddress & ",Belfast"
    Session("src1") = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=" & Session("recentAddressmap1") & "&size=500x300&sensor=false"
    'MsgBox(Session("src1"))
    visualAddress1.Attributes.Add("src", Session("src1"))
End Sub
```

End Class

ASPX

```
<%@ Page Title="About Us" Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeBehind="About.aspx.vb" Inherits="email_tester.About" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
               <iframe width="425" height="350" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" id="visualAddress1" runat="server"></iframe>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about give an ID + runat=server to the iframe and then set the src from VB?